# AutoCompleteTextView with SimpleCursorAdapter for loading contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview, android-cursoradapter

Hi I am developing an android SMS app where in I am using an AutoCompleteTextView for searching contacts using SimpleCursorAdapter as in below code.

```
    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextContact);
    mTxtPhoneNo.setOnClickListener(this);

    phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID ,null, null);
    String[] columns = new String[] 
            {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE

            };

    adapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custcontview, phones ,columns, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });
    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The search string can be either number or the contact name. How can I search using SimpleCursorAdapter. I am very new to CursorAdapter and have very less knowledge on it. Please Help with any related sample code or related links.

Thanks!

Comment: this link may helpful for you..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mPeopleList;

    private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mTxtPhoneNo;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        PopulatePeopleList();
        mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);

        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview ,new String[] { "Name", "Phone" , "Type" }, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });

        mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

    public void PopulatePeopleList()
    {

    mPeopleList.clear();

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (people.moveToNext())
    {
    String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

    String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

    if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0))
    {

    // You know have the number so now query it like this
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,
    null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

    //store numbers and display a dialog letting the user select which.
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(
    phones.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();

    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);

    if(numberType.equals("0"))
    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
    else
    if(numberType.equals("1"))
    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
    else if(numberType.equals("2"))
    NamePhoneType.put("Type",  "Mobile");
    else
    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");

    //Then add this map to the list.
    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
    }
    phones.close();
    }
    }
    people.close();

    startManagingCursor(people);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have used this previously. This loads the activity very slowly almost like 7 to 8 seconds. How to load it faster using cursor adapter

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Show_Phone_Contacts_In_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=106&aaid=128

Comment: Thanks for the link. But even makes the activity load slow. How to fix it?

Comment: wait a few minute i will gwt back you having some work

Comment: @DigveshPatel, I have the same problem with slow activity load. Can you help??

Comment: @LazyCoder  startManagingCursor() is an old way of managing a cursor.  A Loader should be advocated instead...